# How do I get PhpMyAdmin to see my website's database?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm a layman when it comes to web servers, anyhow I have set a lamp server for personal use (it's only accessible locally) in an Ubuntu 17.04 machine and I can access my website normally when I type http://localhost/ or http://127.0.0.1/
So I installed PhpMyAdmin from the official repos and I can also access it from http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ but it only shows it's own database in the interface, but I would like it to access my website's database instead.

Answer (score 1):

PPHMyAdmin can connect to both local and remote databases.

Adjust the config file to hardcode a hostnames. Place the following content in `/etc/phpmyadmin/conf.d/default-login.inc.php`. This can be used to allow direct access to your database.

It can also be tweaked, if needed, to require a password on connect, by just specifying the host.

```
<?php

  // No password login information

  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'config';
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'USERNAME';
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'PASSWORDHERE';
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
```